# Run-time error 438 trying to pull a Dynamic array from an external excel sheet in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, worksheet-function, worksheet

I am running my code from an excel file that is intended to aggregate data from a bunch of other excel file. I want to pull an array from an excel file called "Cases Received" but I get a runtime error 438: Object does not support this property or method.

```
Dim srcWarehouse As Workbook
'Storing the worksheet with my desired data as a variable with the object type workbook'
Set srcWarehouse = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\christian.pignataro\Documents\Timeline Accuracy project\Cases Received 2021.xlsx", True, True)


Dim numbers() As Integer, size As Integer, i As Integer

'This next line is the line that throws the error it is intended to use the worksheet function
'CountA to count the length of the array since the size of the listed data on the Cases 
'Received workbook will change each month
size = srcWarehouse.Worksheets("Sheet1").WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets(1).Columns(1))

ReDim numbers(size)
For i = 1 To size
    numbers(i) = srcWarehouse.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value
Next i

MsgBox numbers(size)
```

Comment: A `Worksheet` does not have a `WorksheetFunction` property. It's `Application.WorksheetFunction`.

Comment: If it worked, add it as an answer, and then accept the answer. Do NOT edit a question to include `Sovled` in the title.